# Upload image from jquery modal popup

Tags: jquery, upload

I want to upload an image with other fields that is presented in jquery modal popup. 
I've seen some answers here like, we can use iframe to upload image from jquery modal dialog, But i couln't understand cleary.. Can some one tell me how to do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Gidon's recommendation is a good one (+1) another alternative is the [uploadify plugin](http://www.uploadify.com/), just to give you options.

**Edited for file upload php**

```
<?php


    $error = "";
    $msg = "";
    $filepath = "";
    $fileElementName = $_REQUEST['field'];  //input name

    if(!empty($_FILES[$fileElementName]['error']))
    {
        switch($_FILES[$fileElementName]['error'])
        {
            case '1':
                $error = 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini';
                break;
            case '2':
                $error = 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form';
                break;
            case '3':
                $error = 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded';
                break;
            case '4':
                $error = 'No file was uploaded.';
                break;

            case '6':
                $error = 'Missing a temporary folder';
                break;
            case '7':
                $error = 'Failed to write file to disk';
                break;
            case '8':
                $error = 'File upload stopped by extension';
                break;
            case '999':
            default:
                $error = 'No error code avaiable';
        }
    }
    elseif(empty($_FILES[$fileElementName]['tmp_name']) || $_FILES[$fileElementName]['tmp_name'] == 'none')
    {
        $error = 'No file was uploaded..';
    }
    else 
    {
            $uploaddir = '../../images/content/';
            $uploadname = substr(basename($_FILES[$fileElementName]['name']), -4);
            $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $uploadname;

            if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fileElementName]['tmp_name'], $uploadfile )) 
            {
                // Save image information to db or whatever you want to do here
                $addon_message = "File (" . $uploadfile . ") moved successfully.";
            } else {
                $addon_message = "File failed to copy.";
            }
            /* ----- */
            $msg .= " File Name: " . $_FILES[$fileElementName]['name'] . ", ";
            $msg .= " File Size: " . @filesize($_FILES[$fileElementName]['tmp_name']);
            $msg .= $addon_message;
            $filepath = substr($uploadfile, 3);
            //for security reason, we force to remove all uploaded file
            @unlink($_FILES[$fileElementName]);     
    }       
    echo "{";
    echo                "error: '" . $error . "',\n";
    echo                "msg: '" . $msg . "',\n";
    echo                "filepath: '" . $filepath . "'\n";
    echo "}";
?>
```

Comment: I used uploadify, and although it's quite nice, I disliked the fact that it doesn't post with the user's cookie (which contains the session id etc). So I had to build an additional validation , to check which user uploaded the file.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin. It handles uploading files neatly.

Comment: nice link Gidon. Whether "$_POST['mimetype']" will get the posted image?. I've seen this in that page. Click Files.php in the following page. http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload

Comment: I'm not a PHP person, but what I understand is that $_POST['mimetype'] gets the value that was submitted in the select box (it's name is mimetype).  To get the file(s) , see the code section on the bottom. $_FILES is an array of all the files submitted.

Comment: @Sekar - I've added a simple image upload (php) code to my answer, hopefully that will that will get you going.